# Non-standard signature of main() compiles successfully

Tags: c, program-entry-point

In this code:

```
int main(int a, int b)
{
    printf(" main(int, int) works \n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

the signature of `main` is `main(int, int)`, and [it compiles successfully](http://ideone.com/wefAC). Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the C standard doesn't prohibit non-standard signatures for `main` (see e.g. section 5.1.2 of the C99 standard).

However, you'll find that if you compile under GCC with the `-Wall` flag,<sup>1</sup> it will complain:

```
test.c:4: warning: second argument of 'main' should be 'char **'
```

It assumes that you want to interact with a standard environment (i.e. process command-line parameters and return an exit status), in which case you must use `int main(int, char **)` or `int main(void)`.  If you use anything else, the contents of the arguments will be undefined.

---

<sub>1. I really wish ideone.com would allow you to specify compiler flags!</sub>

Comment: about note (1): choosing "C99 strict" looks like passing *-std=c99 -pedantic  -Werror*

Answer (score 3):

The C standard specifically prohibits the implementation from providing a prototype for `main` (C99, §5.1.2.2.1/1: "The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function."), and a mismatch from the prototype is what would (normally) stop the code from compiling.

Without a prototype, you're back to programming like in the bad old days, when it was up to you to ensure that the arguments you passed to a function matched what it expected. Thankfully in the case of `main`, the signature is so well known that it's rarely a problem though.

Edit: note that if you want to badly enough, it's actually even possible to make use of the version with two `int` parameters (though the technique is prohibited in C++). `main` can call itself recursively, and in such a case can/could pass two `int` parameters:

```
int main(int a, int b) { 
     if (a == 2)
         main(2, 10);

     printf("%d, %d", a, b);
     return 0;
}
```

This is pretty useless as it stands, but gives the general idea -- you're expected to run the program with no command line arguments, in which case `a` (which will receive what you normally call `argc`) will normally be `1` (i.e., the only argument it's trying to pass is the name of the program in argv[0]). In this case, it calls itself with some other values. When that happens, it prints out those values.

To be fair, I should add that that's pretty close to purely theoretical, and certainly not recommended. It'll work with most typical implementations, but the standard doesn't guarantee it. It's a silly, roundabout way to accomplishing what it does -- but at least with most typical compilers, it is (just barely) possible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no header file that specifies the signature of main, so no error will be reported. The compiler usually checks the return value only, for the case of main (the warnings of the signature of main is compiler dependent).

Comment: `There is no header file that specifies the signature of main, so no error will be reported`. I don't think you are right here.

Comment: @nims The error reported by compiler is not the one identified by header file since there is no header for main. That error is generated by special logic of compiler specific to main.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int a, int b)
```

this is meaningless as the arguments passed to the main function are always

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
```

main is an unusual function.It is called by the operating system, and as C++ can run on many systems and the C++ standards cannot dictate to OS writers what data they pass to programs running on that OS - you can write any parameters you like in the main functions and the compiler will accept it.